# $\ell$-adic cohomology of a quotient by group action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-cohomology, etale-cohomology, deligne-lusztig-theory

Suppose $Y \to Y/G$ is the Galois cover induced from a finite group $G$ acting on a scheme $Y$ and that this is indeed a Galois cover with $Y/G$ a scheme. In my case $Y$ is the Drinfeld curve $\mathrm{spec}\left(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}[x,y]/(xy^q - yx^q - 1)\right)$ and $G = \mu_{q+1}$ acting by $(x,y) \mapsto (\zeta x, \zeta y)$. Then it seems that $H_c^r(Y/G) \cong H_c^r(Y)^G$ for all $r$.

This will indeed follow, for example, if the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence for the constant sheaves
$$
H^s(G,H^r_c(Y,\underline{\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}})) \implies H^{r+s}_c(Y/G,\underline{\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}})
$$
degenerate at the second page, but I do not see why this is true. Is there maybe another way to see this? I am new to étale cohomology.

Comment: What are your coefficients in $H^r_c(Y/G)$?

Comment: @abx coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$.

Comment: Well, if you are working with l-adic coefficients (characteristic zero field), the finite group $G$ has no higher cohomology (taking fixed points is an exact functor), so the only column that contributes to $E_2$ is $s = 0$, so this clearly degenerates. Right? If you took coefficients in l-adic integers or modulo l, you would have to be more careful (i.e. taking derived invariants).

Comment: @DanielJuteau Thats sounds good, but to get l-adic cohomology you need to take the inverse limit of these constant sheaves Z/l^nZ. Do I need to take an inverse limit of spectral sequences to achieve the result?

Comment: If the action if $G$ is “free”, then etale locally on $Y/G$, the pushforward of the etale sheaf $\mu_{\ell^n}$ is a permutation module for $G$.  So the higher group cohomology of the pushforward sheaf vanishes.

Comment: ... In that case, the adjunction homomorphism for invariants is an isomorphism of etale sheaves on $Y/G$ from $\mu_{\ell^n}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[G]$ to the pushforward sheaf.  This sheaf isomorphism induces and isomorphism of cohomology modules.  Since cohomology is an additive functor, this is an isomorphism from $H^*(Y/G,\mu_{\ell^n})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}[G]$ to $H^*(Y,\mu_{\ell^n})$ as $G$-modules.  Now take $G$-invariants to get the isomorphism.

Comment: Following on Daniel Juteau's comment: With $\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell$, this is indeed automatic. When you reduce to $\mathbb Z/\ell^n\mathbb Z$, there may be cohomology groups, but they are all killed by $|G|$, and hence stay so after passing to the limit over $n$, so that when inverting $\ell$, they disappear.